# Search Engine way to take .ASP pages to .PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic, search-engine

I have basic .ASP pages running on a windows box.  I want to migrate them over to a Linux host and of course have to convert them to .PHP and keep like Google happy.

If my site's fairly popular in the search engines how is the best way to do this?

There's a lot out there on the net about this, I just want to make sure I'm going at it the right way.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

Use mod_rewrite to keep your ASP extensions and point it to PHP files of the same name (except for the extension, of course)

Alternatively, use mod_rewrite to do a 301 redirect so that Google updates it's .asp references to the .php URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I like great_llama's answer, but there is also the option of configuring apache to parse .asp pages as php.

The way I know to do this is to put this in your .htaccess file or apache config.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp
```

Then you could keep your .asp extenions, but run everything as php.  This would become a pain over time though, I only suggest it here as another alternative, perhaps as a temporary solution.